How to connect to MariaDB Server via OpenVPN
My problem is probably super trivial, but I'm really completely new to these topics.
I have a virtual server (Ubuntu 24.04, Plesk) with a fixed IP (123.123.123.123 in the example) with my provider IONOS. This serves as an OpenVPN server and also as a host for a MariaDB (accessible for localhost only).
I can connect to the OpenVPN server with my Windows VPN clients.
But the Windows application can only communicate with the MariaDB if I make it publicly accessible and not just for localhost.
My vpnserver.conf looks like this:
port 1194
proto tcp4
dev tun
 
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
 
keepalive 10 120

topology subnet
 
remote-cert-tls client
server 10.8.1.0 255.255.255.0

push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
 
ca ca.crt
cert vpnserver.crt
key vpnserver.key
dh dh.pem
 
tls-crypt ta.key
cipher AES-256-GCM

auth SHA512
tls-version-min 1.2
verb 3

The Windows application accesses the DB server directly via a corresponding ODBC connector, i.e. 123.123.123.123:3306 (and user/password of course).
Exactly this access is to be tunneled via OpenVPN, sigh.
Now the question is whether I still need routes or port forwarding etc. somewhere.
In the UFW of the server is entered:
#   ufw-before-output
#   ufw-before-forward
    
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o ens6 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT


I doubt it's feasible to use a full blown VPN just to facilitate a connection to MySQL over the secure channel. First of all, MySQL supports TLS itself and it can use the very same certificates for client authentication that OpenVPN is using and that will have the same level of security without unnecessary complicating networking, secondly, SSH forwarding will be easiest way and with it you don't need to listen on TCP nor making MySQL listen on TCP; everything can be done using Unix domain sockets.

Concerning the SSH forwarding I hope I understand it correctly: If I want to access the MySQL database (only accessible from localhost) of my remote server, which has the public IP address 11.22.33.44, I use local port forwarding.
For example
ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:3306 -N -f user@11.22.33.44
In my local application, I can then reach the MariaSQL server at 11.22.33.44:3306 and the data traffic is encrypted?

With this command you access MariaDB server with local application at localhost:5901, and all the data will be tunneled through SSH connection, encrypted of course. If you're on Linux, however, no need to use TCP at all, I suggest to use something like ssh -L /tmp/mysql.sock:/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock -N -f user@11.22.33.44, and local applications should pick up a socket at default path without even explicit specifying it (you may adjust paths as needed, of course). Less TCP is better. The caveat in this case is socket auth won't work

The only thing you need to change in your firewall is to explicitly allow traffic from your VPN subnet to connect to the MySQL port (usually 3306).
You may need to check your authentication setup in MariaDB to ensure the accounts you are using are allowed to sign in using the an IP address in the openvpn subnet.
BTW if you are not using a custom DNS server then there's no point in forcing your DNS traffic via the openvpn connection - all you are doing is slowing down clients and using more bandwidth via your VPS. Forcing the client to use the VPN for all traffic is much worse.

Well except accessible for localhost only. He would either need to make it listen to the VPN IP, or maybe REDIRECT to 127.0.0.1 (might need to mess with the route_localnet sysctl as well).

Would it work if I insert
push “route 123.123.123.123 255.255.255.255”
instead of
push “redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp”?
And in the firewall rules something like
ufw allow from 10.8.0.0/8 to 123.123.123.123 port 3306

You can test that on your setup. We can't (I don't think it will work).

I gave up and am now using sth. like
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 -N SSHuser@123.123.123.123
